# Speech to text with JS example no working

Tags: azure, bing, azure-cognitive-services

I'm try to run example on my computer (https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/Speech-api/documentation/GetStarted/GetStartedJS) but when I select "Use Microphone" nothing happend, checking code, exactly in [88 line](https://github.com/Microsoft/Cognitive-Speech-STT-JavaScript/blob/master/index.htm#L88), when timeout is finished, the captured data **is not send**, looking documentation I don't know how to retrieve BufferArray recorded, how to get it? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

reaching out as we did not respond to your request to look into the JS problem you were experiencing . The issue has been fixed.